# dynamicly nested object from another object

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

trying to figure out how to dynamicly create a new nested object from this one:

```
object1 = {
    DataStore : false,
    Header: false,
    Footer : false,
    Sidebar : false,
    Main : false,
    }
```

to nested one like this:

```
const registerComponentsLocal = {
    'DataStore': {
        'debug': false
    },
    'Header': {
        'debug': false
    },
    'Footer': {
        'debug': false
    },
    'Sidebar': {
        'debug': false
    },
    'Main': {
        'debug': false
    },
}
```

keys and values have to by dynamic. Only important thing is a structure of the final object.
Any ideas would be greatly appricieated.

Comment: `Object.entries(object1).reduce((a, [k, v]) => { a[k] = {debug: v}; return a; }, {});`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a **new** instance (i.e preserve the old one)

```
let originalObject = {
    DataStore : false,
    Header: false,
    Footer : false,
    Sidebar : false,
    Main : false,
    }

let newObject = Object.assign({}, originalObject) // Copies the original object
Object.entries(newObject).forEach(([key, value]) => newObject[key] = {debug: value})
```

Comment: seams like I was quite close. Impressive to receive the answer minutes if not seconds after posting a question. well done

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using `reduce`

```
Object.entries(object1)
   .reduce((b,a) => ({...b, [a[0]] : {debug:a[1]}}), {})
```

To iterate, we need an array and `Object.entries` gives us that. Then, using `reduce`, we iterate through each item in `object1`, and build a result. Here, this line `({...b, [a[0]] : {debug:a[1]}})` takes our accumulating object `b` and adds in the next iterable: {key: { debug: value}}`

```js
let object1 = {
    DataStore : false,
    Header: false,
    Footer : false,
    Sidebar : false,
    Main : false,
    }
     
const registerComponentsLocal = Object.entries(object1).reduce((b,a) => ( {...b, [a[0]] : { debug:a[1]} }),{})
console.log(registerComponentsLocal)
```